# How to convert topic name into smaller case using tranform method available in confluent properties

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using JDBC kafka connector for taking data from oracle to kafka topics. I have topic names defined in small case. But, as by default properties are defined in quotes so Oracle is taking everything as case sensitive. I have set quote.sql.identifiers=NEVER as well but it is not working for me. Only way left for me is to transform topic name.

topic.prefix=ab_gh.cc_kk_gh.

table.whitelist=XGH_YTUG_GHH

so topic name is coming as ab_gh.cc_kk_gh.XGH_YTUG_GHH but i have a need of ab_gh.cc_kk_gh.xgh_ytug_ghh
basically, I need table name in small case to be appended to the topic.prefix.

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

You can use transformation to do that:

1. Add static field with value, taht will be used as topic name Use
2. ExtractTopic Transformation to set topic name extracted from message

Sample configuration might look as follow:

```js
{
    ...
    "transforms": "InsertTableName, ExtractTopic",
    "transforms.InsertTableName.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
    "transforms.InsertTableName.static.field": "newTopicName",
    "transforms.InsertTableName.static.value": "ab_gh.cc_kk_gh.xgh.ytug.ghh",
    "transforms.ExtractTopic.type": "io.confluent.connect.transforms.ExtractTopic$Value",
    "transforms.ExtractTopic.field": "newTopicName",
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi,Actually I have n number of tables, static case will not work. I have to end up creating n source connector file. Is there any other way by which I can convert it into lower case. If yes, please help.

Comment: @user147296, you have to create your own transformation, that will do that.